# Where base and limit registers are located?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, cpu-registers, main-memory-database

Where base and limit registers are located?

1. Are there in CPU or somewhere else?
2. Base and limit addresses are different for each process. So, how can CPU knows the value of these registers for each process?

**EDIT**:
Every process has a place on memory, starting address(base) and ending address(base+limit). By looking those address cpu does not execute any operation on those address ranges in order not to effect other processes' memory. So, every process has a starting address(base). My question is, how cpu get this addresses which varies from process to process

Comment: these are CPU registers and it is not clear what specifically you want to ask about location. there is only one set of these registers used by all processes.

Comment: Every process has a place on memory, starting address(base) and ending address(base+limit). By looking those address cpu does not execute any operation on those address ranges in order not to effect other processes' memory. So, every process has a starting address(base). My question is, how cpu get this addresses ehich varies from process to process

Comment: in process control block of each process

Answer (score 2):

What you're probably referring to is a technique called **segmentation** used for example in x86 compatible CPUs. In the past this has been used to separate multiple processes in memory from each other, though this is no longer common nowadays and hardware support for segmentation has even been removed in newer processors.

Memory references (both for code and data) are "prefixed" with a so called **segment selector**. On x86, these are the registers `CS` (for instruction loading), `DS` (data access, e.g. by `mov`), `SS` (stack access), `ES` (destination of e.g. `movs`), `FS` and `GS`.

Depending on the segment selector the CPU will use one of the **segment descriptors** (provided by the operating system) to add that segments base address to the memory address, and check whether the address stays within the specified limit. (There are other checks, like privilege level, execution permission, ...)

```
physical address = logical address + segment base
```

The resulting address is the one actually used to fetch data from main memory.

These segment descriptors are part of either the **global descriptor table** or of some **local descriptor table**, set up by the operating system or the user process, respectively. These tables are stored somewhere in main memory (the CPU gets their addresses using `lgdt` or `lldt` instructions).

To avoid having to perform two memory accesses on each access (one to lookup the segment descriptor plus the intended one) the currently used segment descriptors are cached in some CPU internal registers. This becomes obvious when switching e.g. the global descriptor table, because in order for this to take effect one needs to reset every segment selector.

Thus ...

> Are there in CPU or somewhere else?

... the answer is "in main memory, but cached internally in the CPU".

> Base and limit addresses are different for each process. So, how can CPU knows the value of these registers for each process?

Upon task switch, either the operating system (for software multitasking) or the CPU itself (when using hardware multitasking, via another descriptor structure called task state segment) changes the segment selectors in the `CS`, `DS`, ... registers. This changes the used segment descriptors, and thus the used base and limit addresses.